# html canvas ctx.fillRect() to mouse position

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic `javascript` app where the canvas has a grid with cells 35px each.
when the user clicks in the cell i need to `ctx.fillRect()` in that cell.

Currently the `ctx.fillRect()` does not draw in the cell where the tip of the mouse is. it only draws in that cell when the mouse is in the top left of the desired cell.

i assume its just a simple math problem. However i suck at math and cant seem to work it out. Could someone assist with this please.

```js
    var grid_size = 35;
    var mouseX, mouseY;
    main_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    main_ctx = main_canvas.getContext("2d");

    
    track_canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    track_ctx = main_canvas.getContext("2d");
    



    var map_code = [];
    var track_code;
    

    
    function draw_track() {

        
        main_ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        main_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 70, 70);
        main_ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        main_ctx.fillRect(140, 0, 35, 35);
       // draw_toggle_grid();

    }

    var toggle_grid = false;
    function draw_toggle_grid() {
        if (toggle_grid == false) {
            main_ctx.fillStyle = "grey";

            row_position = grid_size;
            Column_position = grid_size;
            while (Column_position < main_canvas.width) {
                main_ctx.fillRect(Column_position, 0, 1, main_canvas.height);
                // track_code = row_position;
                Column_position = Column_position + grid_size;
            }
            while (row_position < main_canvas.height) {
                main_ctx.fillRect(0, row_position, main_canvas.width, 1);
                //track_code = row_position;
                row_position = row_position + grid_size;
            }
            toggle_grid = true;
        }
        else {
            main_ctx.fillStyle = "green";
            row_position = grid_size;
            Column_position = grid_size;
            while (Column_position < main_canvas.width) {
                main_ctx.fillRect(Column_position, 0, 1, main_canvas.height);
                // track_code = row_position;
                Column_position = Column_position + grid_size;
            }
            while (row_position < main_canvas.height) {
                main_ctx.fillRect(0, row_position, main_canvas.width, 1);
                //track_code = row_position;
                row_position = row_position + grid_size;
            }

            toggle_grid = false;


        }
    }


    function draw_background() {
        main_ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        main_ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //    draw_track();
    }
    draw_background() 



    draw_toggle_grid();




    function hover_highlight_grid_cell() {
        Closet_Y.innerText = Math.round(mouseY / grid_size) * grid_size;
        Closet_X.innerText = Math.round(mouseX / grid_size) * grid_size;

        var y = Math.round(mouseY / grid_size ) * grid_size;
        var x = Math.round(mouseX / grid_size) * grid_size ;

        

       


        if (toggle_grid == true) {
            
            main_ctx.fillStyle = "red";
            main_ctx.fillRect(x * 0.5, y * 0.5, grid_size, grid_size);

          //  main_ctx.fillRect(b, a, grid_size, grid_size);

        }
        

    }

    
    main_canvas.onmousemove = function (e) {
        

        if (e.offsetX) {
            mouseX = e.offsetX;
            mouseY = e.offsetY;
        }
        else if (e.layerX) {
            mouseX = e.layerX;
            mouseY = e.layerY;
        }

        mouse_cord_Y.innerText = mouseY;
        mouse_cord_X.innerText = mouseX;
      //  hover_highlight_grid_cell()
    };




    function canvasClick(){
        Closet_Y.innerText = Math.round(mouseY / grid_size) * grid_size;
        Closet_X.innerText = Math.round(mouseX / grid_size) * grid_size;

        var y = Math.round(mouseY / 35) * 35;
        var x = Math.round(mouseX / 35) * 35;




            main_ctx.fillStyle = "red";
          //  main_ctx.fillRect(mouseX, mouseY, grid_size, grid_size);

              main_ctx.fillRect(x, y, grid_size, grid_size);


    }
```

```html
   <div>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="910" height="700" onclick="canvasClick();"></canvas>
    <button onclick="draw_toggle_grid()" type="button">draw_toggle_grid</button>
        </div>


    <div>
        <label>Mouse Cords: </label>
        <label id="mouse_cord_X"></label>
        <label>X</label>
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
        <label id="mouse_cord_Y"></label>
        <label>Y</label>
    </div>

    <div>
        <label>Track Code: </label>
        <label id="track_code"></label>

    </div>

     <div>
        <label>Closet Y: </label>
        <label id="Closet_Y"></label>
         <label>&nbsp;</label>
         <label>Closet X: </label>
        <label id="Closet_X"></label>
    </div>

    <label id="thisid"></label>
```

Comment: var y = parseInt(mouseY / 35, 35) * 35;
        var x = parseInt(mouseX / 35, 35) * 35;

Comment: that seems to work correctly in 315x315 area on the canva, but when clicking outside that area it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i solved this by rounding down my mouse cords to the nearest cell size number (35).

I used this to round down: Math.floor(mouseY / 35) * 35